# device lock on only one application

Tags: android, device

We have a project we need to complete at work, however the coding is done and the app works.

What I need to know, how do I take an Android tablet and change the OS that when the device is turned on the device must open up with a logo when started up, to say (ABC with the logo) and then the application we have designed should automatically open up and start running the operation.

In the same sentence, all apps should be blocked out and only the one app should be opened and should work, with internet connectivity.

Comment: you need to root the phone and then add the animated zip inside the media folder in `system/media`
as `bootanimation.zip` or the name that the current file has. Only andoid 10 will support changing the boot animation out of the box.
For setting only a single app I guess you need to make it the default launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different options,

1) [Google Dedicated Device](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices#testing-plan)

2) [Fully Managed Device](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements/fully-managed-device)

3) [mason](https://bymason.com/)

4) [SureLock for Android](https://www.42gears.com/products/surelock/surelock-android/)